# getJSON not retrieving data from tastypie web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, tastypie

So I have a bit of javascript code that gets called when a button gets clicked and is supposed to retrieve some JSON data that I have in a web service app I made by using django/tastypie. The function gets called just fine (I tested it with a simple alert()). I am even getting the GET requests which can be seen in my terminal, however it seems like no data is getting retrieved. I also have an alert() function that isn't getting called inside the anonymous inner-function that gets called. Help.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script)

function funktion(){


$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/event/?format=json", function(data){
    alert("woo");    
    $.each(data, function(keys, values){
               $("<ul/>").append("<li>"+values.name+"</li>");
        });
    }
);
};
```

---UPDATE----

Results from url:

```
{
"meta": {"limit": 20, "next": null, "offset": 0, "previous": null, "total_count": 1}, 
"objects": [
    { "category": "Default",
      "date": "2014-11-08T17:50:37",
      "description": "Hackity hack hack",
      "id": 1,
      "location": "USC",
      "name": "HackSC 2014",
      "num_attendees": 0, 
      "resource_uri": "/api/v1/event/1/"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: So what is the result of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/event/?format=json` when you open in in separate tab?

Comment: Please test this url in browser and print what you got?

Comment: or you can alert(data) instead to check the content of it

Comment: Posted the results. Tried doing alert(data) but doesn't seem to get called for some reason